# Room allotment sql query

Tags: sql

I have following data
1. No.of students based on course Id
2. No.of seats available in a room

I need to arrange students in following style

[image: Room allotment style]
Number of students vary based on course. No.of seats in each room is different. In each room there will be multiple course students. In one desk/chair different course student have to sit.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You don't do this in SQL. Just grab all the data in a list sequentially. This kind of arrangement is done in the client program that class the SQL, at the presentation level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joel Coehoorn . But i need to insert this data to an SQL table. Is it possible to do the entire class seat allotment with a single button click and that result should be store it in an SQL table

Comment: There is no possible good reason to need to store the data in a table that way. Rethink the schema.